# Only portion of text visible in textfield

Tags: css, html

I have a long text which does not fit in the column and therefore I would like to hide the text like Github does it with URL repositories (see picture below).

[image]

How is it possible to implement it or is there already code available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `overflow: hidden` css property:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! How would it be possible to add a copy to clipboard button?

Comment: Thank you, but will it work in smart phones, because of Flash or is anything out without Flash?

Comment: As you can see the github.com doesn't have copy-to-clipboard button in mobile devices. Unfortunately zeroclipboard is the only way to copy text on JavaScript.

Comment: I tried to used zeroclipboard and the above solution, but I was not able to get it to work (please see [here](http://www.bootply.com/qqofKBZV28)). How is it possible fix it?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ZeroClipboard is not defined" on the console. Are you include ZeroClipboard plugin to your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS question. You may analyse the Github formatting of the text entry field and find out how it is done.